# Confusion about inheritance & access level

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've got some confusions on the access level in C++ inheritance and more generally how I should design a C++ class.

```
class Car
{
public:

private:
    string brandName;
}

class Sedan: public Car
{
public:
    // this function needs to know the Sedan's brandName
    void someFun()
    {
        brandName = "sss"; // error!!!    
    }
private:
}
```

In the above example the Car as a base class has a private member "brandName", and the Sedan as a derived class from Car inherits that member "brandName". As explained in Effective C++, public inheritance makes an "is-a" relationship, which means Sedan is a Car, now can I say that Sedan has a "brandName"?. If the answer is yes, why couldn't Sedan access to its own attribute in someFun?

I know the solution is to change brandName's access level to protected, my confusion is that what features or conditions make a variable member to which access level, in other word how I decide which access level should a given member be attached to?

I'd also like it if you'd recommend any book or article elaborating on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> now can I say that Sedan has a "brandName"?

No, neither has `Car`. The `brandName` is an implementatin detail, private, hidden from anyone else and does not contribute to the class' public interface, which is what makes the nature of a `Car`. So while technically there is a brandName somewhere in a Car and thus in a Sedan, from a pure OO view that does not matter. Similar to "Is-A"-relationships that are expressed only by *public* inheritance and not by private inheritance, "Has-A"-relationships in the OO point of view are only present if the composition or assoctiation is publicly accessible/visible (mostly via getters/setters).

juanchopanza's answer and the comments to it have lead me to sneak a little around the web, trying to find resources about Is-A and Has-An relationships. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2219036/1838266) transcription seems to indicate that the two terms did not originate from OO thoughts. In fact, OO literature seems to cite the Liskov Substitution Principle instead of using "Is-A" relationships. It lays stress on encapsulation and opaque objects, so it concerns mostly with public interfaces of classes and how their behavior affect *associated* objects. While a "Has-A" relationship can be association, it also can be aggregation. In this case, since the `brandName` is not an external, associated object (in C++ we would express that fact with a pointer or reference member), it is an aggregation-"Has-A", hidden in the opaque `Car` and therefore not of interest for OO (and the above answer is left semantically valid).

> I know the solution is to change brandName's access level to protected

NO! `brandName`'s access level has to remain private, so that `Car` has the complete control over what happens to it. If you want to access it in derived classes, provide protected getters and/or setters.

> I'd also like it if you'd recommend any book or article elaborating on this topic.

Any book about object oriented design should do. If you read through two or more of them, you will get a good idea of what to do and what not to do.

Comment: Or make the field protected.

Comment: @BillyONeal as I have written in the answer, making the field protected gives any deriving class ucontrolled, free access to it, breaking encapsulation. It's the little brother of making it public.

Comment: @ArneMertz so in what condition do we need to consider using protected?

Comment: @ArneMertz: Making getters and setters is also little better than making it public.

Comment: @BillyONeal getters and setters can be monitored, can contain consistency checks or can be constrained tp readonly, i.e. only the getter and no setter. You have control over what happens in a getter/setter, which you dont have exposing the raw variable in the public/protected interface. You have more means to refactor. But this is old coffee, you can read it up in any good book that covers the topic.

Comment: @Norwizki its not about avoiding protected. It's about not exposing raw member variables in apublic/protected interface, but to use accessor methods. Either plain getters/setters or more sophisticated functions.

Answer (score 2):

> can I say that Sedan has a "brandName"?.

Yes, it certainly has an object of type `string` called `Car::brandName` (whether this constitutes an OOP "has-a" relationship isn't entirely clear to me, but probably not: see comments)

> If the answer is yes, why couldn't Sedan access to its own attribute in someFun?

Simple because `brandName` is `private`. Those are the rules of the language. If you want to give a derived class access to a non-public data member, you can make it `protected`.

> I'd also like it if you'd recommend any book or article elaborating on this topic.

There is a [list of books here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Perhaps "The C++ Programming Language" would be good for explaining this particular aspect.

Comment: "Yes, it does" - from a technical view, yes. From the OO view, wich I think is what the question is about, no, because it's not part of its interface.

Comment: @ArneMertz I am not sure has-a implies that the object must be part of the public interface. If you have references to this effect, I would be interested in reading them.

Comment: I have to confess, I have no references. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2219036/1838266) is what i found while searching: Is-A and Has-A seem to be not original OO-terms. Is-A in OO terms would be the Liskov Substitution Principle, while in a strict OO view objects should be opaque, meaning the public interface, behavior and assicitations are vital, while (hidden) aggregation is not.

Comment: @ArneMertz It kind of makes sense after thinking about it. I re-phrased my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Public members are free to all to use.

Private members are for the use of only this current class, and no one else. It is used mostly for inner members of the class to use and save for it's own purposes or to provide a method to access to them.

Protected members are accessible for inherited classes, just as your example shows - brandName is for the use of inherit classes, so it should be protected.

Answer (score 1):

you have hidder **brandName** from the outer world, by making it private. Make it **protected** so that children may inherit it. To understand inheritance rules regarding specifiers, go to [HERE](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/115-inheritance-and-access-specifiers/)

Answer (score 1):

> I've got some confusions on the access level in C++ inheritance and more generally how I should design a C++ class.

C++ has three access level specifiers that can be used when inheriting:

- private, protected and public

**class Derived : public Base**

Is called public inheritance and represents IsA relationship. When inheriting publicly, public members of the base remain public in Derived, protected members remain protected in Derived and private members are private (and not accessible from Derived).

**class Derived : protected Base**
Is called protected inheritance. This kind of inheritance is rare, and would be used if you don't want to expose the public part of Base when accessed as derived (or through the interface of Derived). In this kind of inheritance the public members in base become protected in derived.

[Also see the C++ FAQs](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/access-rules-with-priv-inherit.html)

**class Derived : private Base**

Is called private inheritance. This kind of inheritance can be used to simulate containment ([Herb Sutter - Uses and abuses of inheritance](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm)). Here public members in Base become private when accessed through the interface of derived.

It can also be noted that protected and private inheritance does not represent the classic IsA relationship. The following polymorphic behaviour is only possible when inheriting publicly:

```
Derived d;
Base* b = &d;
```

However, for private inheritance polymorphic behaviour is possible in the first derived class (but not in subsequent).

```
struct Base{};
struct Derived : private Base
{
  Derived()
  {
    //IsA holds within member functions of Derived, but not
    // outside
    Base* b = this; 
  }
};
struct Derived2 : public Derived
{
  Derived2()
  {
    Base* b = this; //Fails to compile...inaccessible base
  }
};
int main()
{
  Derived d;
  Base* b = &d; //Fails to compile
}
```

For protected inheritance polymorphic behaviour is possible in the all subsequent derived classes (Therefore code in constructor of Derived2 here above would compile), but not outside of class member functions.

Herb Sutter comments on reasons for using non public inheritance in [Uses and abuses](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm).

Finally, a comment concerning your example above: Usually Car would be abstract (an interface, consisting only of pure virtual functions), and therefore it would not contain any data members, but leave it open to the implementation. This is a guideline concerning inheritance that I've heard somewhere [Sutter - Exceptional C++](http://books.google.co.za/books?id=58rZvOSuheEC&lpg=PA81&ots=L_QhlzmVRq&dq=inherit%20publicly%20in%20order%20to%20be%20reused%20sutter&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q=inherit%20publicly%20in%20order%20to%20be%20reused%20sutter&f=false):

Inherit publicly in order to be reused by code that uses base classes polymorphically.

Your example would/could become:

```
struct Car
{
  //Note: const used as brandName should not modify logical state.
  virtual const std::string& brandName() const = 0;

  //...virtual ~Car(), amongst others, depending
  // on whether you intend to be deleted via this interface...
};

// Note: public inheritance implied by struct
struct CarFromFile: /*public*/ Car
{
  CarFromFile( std::ifstream& file )
  : brandName_( strFrom( file ) ),
    manufacturer_( strFrom( file )
  {
  }
  virtual const std::string& brandName() const{ return brandName_; }
  private:
    std::string strFrom( std::ifstream& file )
    {
      std::string value;
      if( file >> value ) { return value; }
      throw std::runtime_error( "Invalid file format!" );
    }
    std::string brandName_;
    std::string manufacturer_;
    //etc...
};
```

The fact that you make the accessor abstract, allows freedom from
the perspective of the implementer of derived, and defines the service
required by the client of base, independent of how the actual data looks.

Answer (score 0):

The classifications for `public`, `protected` and `private` are intended to allow one to separate publicly available interfaces from internal implementation details. Thus, things that are not `public` are inaccessible, forcing users of the `class` to use the `public` interfaces provided.

If something is `private`, then even though inheritance will make the member a part of the derived `class`, the derivation is not allowed to access it. If it is desirable to allow a derived `class` access to interfaces and members that are not part of the `public` interface, then that is exactly when to use `protected`.