# Combine separate classes to superclass or not?

Tags: .net, oop, design-patterns

I have the following class structures

```
Category(MustInherit)
```

The following classes inherits Category

```
strongPerson
weakPerson
```

Then I have the class

```
Job (MustInherit)
```

The following classes inherits Job

```
Craft
DeskJob
```

Now the user can can choose come characteristics and create a Person (in this example a craftsman).

```
sub start()
    'Person
    dim s as new strongPerson(...)
    dim j as new craft(...)
sub end
```

My questions:

1. I used to program procedually and the `Sub start()` reminds me a lot of it. Is the approach I choose a good one? If not why? Would it be better do use interfaces and build a class Person (using multi inheritance)?
2. Since there are many more categories and jobs this is going to be
   quite complex with `categories * job posibilities`. Doese there exist a recommendable design pattern? The field of design patterns is quite big and I read through a lot but couldnt find an apropriate one.

Comment: Take a look at the following discussion about "IS-A" and "HAS-A" concepts.  I think it might help you answer your own question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218937/has-a-is-a-terminology-in-object-oriented-language

Comment: How is that sample creating a person?  You have two separate objects that are not tied to each other in any way.

Comment: I thought I print the content of these two objects so the user can see the characteristics in a form but didnt see that there are two objects instead of one. I am really new to oop so this my be really suboptimal.

Comment: Putting them on the same form is not linking the objects.  Is an an astronaut a deskjob or a craft?

Comment: This is a good example for Bridge design pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern