# What is the name of this in C#?

Tags: c#, class, definition, derived

I'm reading a beginner's C# book. Everything was smooth defining objects like this:

```
BaseClass foo = new BaseClass();
```

but then the author, without any explanation, changed the definitions like this:

```
MiClass foo = new DerivedClass();
```

I would like to learn about this in a book or internet but I don't know what words to use to search for this topic.

Comment: The term you are looking for is 'inheritance'.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot 'inheritance' :D

Comment: @user3646717 you also want to put `()` after the constructor, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: 'subtype polymorphism' or 'subtyping' is more specific than inheritance. EDIT. Beat by @DanielA.White...

Comment: @PhilippeParé this is not going to compile anyway, 'object' is not a valid name for a variable.

Comment: @LeonCullens you're right! it should be `@object`

Comment: Leaving aside what it actually is or may be, I'm pretty sure the author did explain the change, before or after making the change. And if he didn't, that's horrendously bad book.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I totally agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term for this is [subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping), or substitution.

When two types have an inheritance relationship, one is said to be a *subtype* and the other is the *supertype*. When this is applicable, a *subtype instance* can be used in a context where a *supertype instance* was expected (the context being a local variable, a field, a parameter, etc).

This is why you may often hear that [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) denotes an [*is-a* relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218937/has-a-is-a-terminology-in-object-oriented-language). Compare with [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) (the practice of including an object as a member of another object), which denotes a *has-a* relationship (and is the other way of achieving [code reuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse) when dealing with classes).

Back to inheritance, if your classes are defined like this, for example:

```
class Banana : Fruit { ... }
```

We'd say that `Banana` (apart from being a `Banana`, obviously) *is a* `Fruit` as well. Because of that relationship, you can do this, obviously:

```
Banana obj = new Banana();
```

But you do this as well:

```
Fruit obj = new Banana();
```

And you can do something similar whenever a field or a method parameter expects a `Fruit`.

This type of relationship is useful when you want parts of your code to use an object, but you don't want them to know too many details about that object (maybe because those details are irrelevant or subject to change). If those parts can do their job with less specific information (in this case, the fact that the object is some kind of `Fruit` and not specifically a `Banana`), then it's preferable to have them work with that. This is a form of [decoupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) and it's a generally desired property of code as a project gets more and more complex.

Comment: Thank you. The book did explained polymorphism and inheritance but never mentioned anything about a definition such as Fruit obj = new Banana(); That is what I didn't even know how to name.