# How to use the methods of the parent class?

Tags: python, inheritance

Here the `SMS_Store` inherits the `Message`, but every time I call the parent method there is the error:

`NoneType object does not have attribute 'read_message'`.

and also the object stored in the list returns a `None` value??

```
class Message():

    def __init__(self, from_number, time_arrived, text_of_sms):
        self.has_been_viewed=False
        self.from_number= from_number
        self.time_arrived = time_arrived
        self.text_of_sms = text_of_sms

    def getTime(self):
        return self.time_arrived

    def getText(self):
        return self.text_of_sms

    def setView(self):
        self.has_been_viewed = True

    def check_read(self):
        return self.has_been_viewed


class SMS_Store(Message):

    def __init__(self):
        self.list_=[]

    def add_new_arrivals(self,from_number, time_arrived, text_of_sms):
        self.list_.append(Message.__init__(self,from_number,time_arrived,text_of_sms))

    def message_count(self):
        return len(self.list_)

    def get_unread_index(self):
        unread =[]
        for i in range(len(self.list_)):
            if(super(SMS_Store,self).check_read() == False):
                unread.append(i)
        return unread

    def read_message(self,index):
        self.list_[index].getText()

    def delete(self,ints):
        a = int(ints)
        self.list_.pop(a)

    def clear():
        for i in list:
            self.list_.pop(i)

inbox = SMS_Store()
inbox.add_new_arrivals(12,9,'some nights i stay up')
inbox.add_new_arrivals(12,5,'cashing in my bad luck')
inbox.add_new_arrivals(14,7,'somenights i call it a draw')
inbox.add_new_arrivals(56,0,'somenights i wish that my lips could built a castle.')
inbox.read_message(0)
```

Comment: Why are you overwriting `__init__()`?

Comment: You shouldn't inherit `SMS_Store` from `Message` if you use it for storing a list of instances of `Message`

Comment: Why are you calling `Message.__init__()` explicitly to create instances of the parent class instead of just using `Message()`?

Comment: `SMS_Store` isn't a kind of `Message`, it's a container of instances of them (i.e. it _has_ one or more instances of them), therefore it shouldn't be a subclass.

Comment: @martineau It made sense when you said it like that. Now, i know clearly  what i should've done. thanks you very much.

Comment: masair: You're welcome. It's a fairly fundamental concept in OOP design. See [**_HAS-A, IS-A terminology in object oriented language_**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218937/has-a-is-a-terminology-in-object-oriented-language) (and numerous other articles on the subject).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear where that error could be coming from since `read_message()` is only called by the `inbox.read_message(0)` statement at the end of your code, which wouldn't produce it (although the return value of the `read_message()` method **is** always `None`, since there's no explicit `return` statement in it).

Regardless, to answer the titular question, to do that explicitly you would use the [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) method—but that's not the problem here which is that the `SMS_Store` class shouldn't be a subclass of `Message` at all, since it's not a specialization of the `Message` class...rather it's a *container* of `Message` instances.

Below is reworked version of your code that shows how to separate these two classes and get most if not all of the methods working. It also now mostly follows [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations.

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self, from_number, time_arrived, text_of_sms):
        self.has_been_viewed = False
        self.from_number = from_number
        self.time_arrived = time_arrived
        self.text_of_sms = text_of_sms

    def get_time(self):
        return self.time_arrived

    def get_text(self):
        return self.text_of_sms

    def set_viewed(self):
        self.has_been_viewed = True

    def check_read(self):
        return self.has_been_viewed


class SMS_Store:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_ = []

    def add_new_arrival(self, from_number, time_arrived, text_of_sms):
        self.list_.append(Message(from_number, time_arrived, text_of_sms))

    def message_count(self):
        return len(self.list_)

    def get_unread_index(self):
        unread = []
        for (i, message) in enumerate(self.list_):
            if not message.check_read():
                unread.append(i)
        return unread

    def read_message(self, index):
        message_text = self.list_[index].get_text()
        self.list_[index].set_viewed()
        return message_text

    def delete(self, index):
        self.list_.pop(index)

    def clear():
        self.list_.clear()

inbox = SMS_Store()

inbox.add_new_arrival(12, 9, 'some nights i stay up')
inbox.add_new_arrival(12, 5, 'cashing in my bad luck')
inbox.add_new_arrival(14, 7, 'somenights i call it a draw')
inbox.add_new_arrival(56, 0, 'somenights i wish that my lips could built a castle.')

print(inbox.get_unread_index())  # -> [0, 1, 2, 3]
print(inbox.read_message(0))     # -> some nights i stay up
print(inbox.get_unread_index())  # -> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was trying to do with my code.oh, this is just beautiful. thank you sir. thanks a million sir..

Comment: I was really confused why the objects were returning None value. thank you for that explanation too

Comment: masair: Once again, you're welcome. Try not to stay up too late... `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use inheritance in this case. Here's corrected version (also fixed code style):

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self, from_number, time_arrived, text_of_sms):
        self.has_been_viewed = False
        self.from_number = from_number
        self.time_arrived = time_arrived
        self.text_of_sms = text_of_sms

    def get_time(self):
        return self.time_arrived

    def get_text(self):
        return self.text_of_sms

    def set_view(self):
        self.has_been_viewed = True

    def check_read(self):
        return self.has_been_viewed


class SMSStore:
    def __init__(self):
        self._list = []

    def add_new_arrivals(self, from_number, time_arrived, text_of_sms):
        self._list.append(Message(from_number, time_arrived, text_of_sms))

    def message_count(self):
        return len(self._list)

    def get_unread_index(self):
        return list(filter(lambda m: not m.check_read(), self._list))

    def read_message(self, index):
        return self._list[index].get_text()

    def delete(self, index):
        a = int(index)
        self._list.pop(a)

    def clear(self):
        self._list = []

inbox = SMSStore()
inbox.add_new_arrivals(12, 9, 'some nights i stay up')
inbox.add_new_arrivals(12, 5, 'cashing in my bad luck')
inbox.add_new_arrivals(14, 7, 'somenights i call it a draw')
inbox.add_new_arrivals(56, 0, 'somenights i wish that my lips could built a castle.')
print(inbox.read_message(0))
```

Comment: thanks man. and eh sorry for the code style , my first question as you could guess. but out of my curiosity, why can't i use inheritance in this case ...

Comment: Because it has no sense: you have a message, and a list of messages. This list is neither message nor kind of message.