# Child Class defined before its parent

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I am writing a program for a shopping cart. Everything is derived from the customer. Every customer has a shopping cart. Therefore I thought to put the shopping cart before the Customer class. When doing this I can't declare Shopping cart as a child of Customer. Any fixes?

```
class ShoppingCart : public Customer
{
    private:
    Item* cart[MAX_SIZE] = {NULL};  //problem  may occur
    int size;

    public:
    void addItem(char* type, char* title, char* description, double price);
    void showCart();
};

class Customer
{
    private:
    int ID, items;
    char* firstName, *lastName;
    ShoppingCart* Cart;

    public:
    Customer(char* userFirst, char* userLast, int userID, ShoppingCart* cart)
    {
        this->ID = userID;
        this->firstName = userFirst;
        this->lastName = userLast;
        this->Cart = cart;
    }
    friend void ShoppingCart::addItem(char* type, char* title, char* description, double price);
};
```

Comment: A shopping cart should not be a customer.

Comment: Look into `std::string`, shared pointers. And avoid friends. Perhaps `std::vector`

Comment: And initialization lists

Comment: "Every customer has a shopping cart." that clearly shows that it is "Has-A" relationship and not "Is-A"

Comment: Thats a good point but I want them to be related. I want the cart to have access to the name of the customer and his ID

Comment: @Slava - so does every canal have a shopping cart!

Comment: @rom "poof" - Leave me out of this

Comment: @Slava so what could I use to show a has-a relationship. I'm kinda teaching myself this.

Comment: @George I have it as a friend function because during the additem function I want to increase the "items" variable

Comment: @Slava yeah that's why I'm here

Comment: @DemarcusSales it is possible that one customer can have more than one shopping card, so inherit one from another is clearly wrong.

Comment: "class ShoppingCart : public Customer" - Is a shopping cart a type of customer? i.e. shoppingcat isa customer

Comment: And a customer might not have a shopping cart. Might just be popping into the shop for a packet of luckies

Comment: There is inheritance, composition and aggregation. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218937/has-a-is-a-terminology-in-object-oriented-language) for more information.

Comment: You already have a "has a" relationship by having ShoppingCart as a member of Customer. You could then have a pointer or reference from the ShoppingCart to the Customer and get rid of the weird subclassing relationship.

Answer (score 1):

As for your problem, no, there is no solution to the problem other than declaring and defining the base class before the derived class. Forward declaration would not work here (As I naively thought), since the child class needs contextual information from the base class.

While the above may work, I would like to point out that you really aren't understanding inheritance. Inheritance is based off a *is a* relationship i.e Derived *is a* Base, not a *has a* relationship, which is what your code is trying to emulate. If you want to emulate a *has a* relationship, then you should make the class `ShoppingCart` a *member* of `Customer`, since that will show that each `Customer` has a shopping cart. Inheritance is not the right method to solve your problem here.

Comment: Is there any way I could make the shopping cart aware of the of the private member variables in customer

Comment: Yes, make `ShoppingCart` a [`friend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) of `Customer`.

Comment: I would highly advise against the use of `friend` here as that breaks encapsulation when setters and getters would work just fine. `friend` should be reserved for special cases like `operator<<` and when you need to write unit tests.

Comment: On the other hand, `public` accessor functions can globally weaken or break encapsulation, while `friend` restricts that break to only trusted classes and  functions. In this case I agree though. Add `removeItem` and `checkout` methods and all the accessibility anyone should need is present in `ShoppingCart`. `ShoppingCart` should be looking after itself, not letting others poke around inside it.