# Multiple URLs same action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I need to share action methods between different controllers. Take for example the following 2 controllers:

```
public class AController : Controller
{
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           //print AController - Index
       }

       public ActionResult Test()
       {
           //print test
       }
}

public class BController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
         //print BController - Index
     }
}
```

Both controllers have an Index method which is different. The Test method however can be called from both controllers. So I want that when the following urls are entered the Test() method will execute:

- AController/Test
- BController/Test

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Comment: what's the point of having two different endpoints which do exactly the same thing?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What you are asking is possible, but it is unlikely that it is the best solution for your problem (whatever that is).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the implementation of the `Test()` action is the same for both controllers, refactor it into a common service:

```
public interface ITestService {
    string Test();
}

public TestService: ITestService {
    public string Test() {
        // common implementation
        return "The test result";
    }
}
```

Then set up [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection) to acquire this service.

Your controllers then can use the common service.

```
public class AController : Controller {

    private readonly ITestService _testService;

    public AController(ITestService testservice) {
        _testService = testservice;
    }

    public ActionResult Test() {
        var vm = new TestViewModel();
        vm.TestResult = _testService.Test();
        return View("Test", vm);
    }
}

public class BController : Controller {

    private readonly ITestService _testService;

    public BController(ITestService testservice) {
        _testService = testservice;
    }

    public ActionResult Test() {
        var vm = new TestViewModel();
        vm.TestResult = _testService.Test();
        return View("Test", vm);
    }
}
```

Because the View `Test.cshtml` is rendered by both controllers, it should be placed in the `Views\Shared\` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own routes as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

So you can define as many routes as you like to point to the "Test" method inside "AController" just like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Atest", "AController/Test",
        defaults: new { controller = "AController", action = "Test" });
routes.MapRoute("Btest", "BController/Test",
        defaults: new { controller = "AController", action = "Test" });
```

But you have to define them before the "default" route because otherwise the entered URL will match the default route conditions and so it will enter that route.

It´s also possible to define the route directly in top of the method.

```
public class AController : Controller
{
    [Route("/Some/Route")]
    public ActionResult Test() 
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to throw in an alternative solution. Create a base controller class to be inherited by the other two. Whatever you have there will be part of the children.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //print AController - Index
    }

    // Add more methods to be shared between the other controllers
}

public class AController : BaseController 
{
    // Has Index method already from parent

    // Unique method for A
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        //print test 1
    }
}

public class BController : BaseController
{
    // Has Index method already from parent

    // Unique method for B
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        //print test 2
    }
}
```

This implements the actual functionality in a single place. We use this method for many projects with no issues.