# Create a link between objects

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript, I've created three different object with some attributes: Person, House and Car.

```
let House = function(city, postalCode, street, streetNumber){

  this.city = city;
  this.postalCode = postalCode;
  this.street = street;
  this.streetNumber = streetNumber;

  return {

    getAddress: function() {

      return {
        'address': {
          'city': city,
          'postalCode': postalCode,
          'street': street,
          'streetNumber': streetNumber
        }
      };

    }

  };

};

let Person = function(name, surname, yearOfBirth, monthOfBirth, dayOfBirth, bornCity, employment){

  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
  this.monthOfBirth = monthOfBirth;
  this.dayOfBirth = dayOfBirth;
  this.bornCity = bornCity;
  this.employment = employment;

  return {

    getFullPerson: function() {

      return {
          'personalInformation': {
            'name': name,
            'surname': surname,
            'dateOfBirth': {
              'year': yearOfBirth,
              'month': monthOfBirth,
              'day': dayOfBirth
            },
            'bornCity': bornCity
          },
          'employment': employment,
          'home': getAddress(), // pseudocode
          'car': getCar() // pseudocode
      };

    }

  };

};
```

I would like to create a link between this objects because I need to call, for example, who person lives inside an house and viceversa; but I've no clear how I can do this.

Comment: you can have an attribute `house` inside `person`, or a common key between these two

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php | [HAS-A, IS-A terminology in object oriented language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2218937) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way:

```js
let House = function(city, postalCode, street, streetNumber){

  this.city = city;
  this.postalCode = postalCode;
  this.street = street;
  this.streetNumber = streetNumber;

  return {

    getAddress: function() {

      return {
        'address': {
          'city': city,
          'postalCode': postalCode,
          'street': street,
          'streetNumber': streetNumber
        }
      };

    }

  };

};

let Person = function(name, surname, yearOfBirth, monthOfBirth, dayOfBirth, bornCity, employment, house, car){

  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
  this.monthOfBirth = monthOfBirth;
  this.dayOfBirth = dayOfBirth;
  this.bornCity = bornCity;
  this.employment = employment;
  this.house = house;
  this.car = car;

  return {

    getFullPerson: function() {

      return {
          'personalInformation': {
            'name': name,
            'surname': surname,
            'dateOfBirth': {
              'year': yearOfBirth,
              'month': monthOfBirth,
              'day': dayOfBirth
            },
            'bornCity': bornCity
          },
          'employment': employment,
          'home': (house ? house.getAddress() : null), // pseudocode
          'car': (car ? car.getCar() : null)  // pseudocode
      };

    }

  };

};

let house1 = new House('city', 'postalCode', 'street', 'streetNumber');

let person1 = new Person('person', '1', 2020, 1, 1, 'bornCity', 'employment', null, null);
let person2 = new Person('person', '2', 2020, 1, 1, 'bornCity', 'employment', house1, null);


console.log(person1.getFullPerson());
console.log(person2.getFullPerson());
```

Create any `House` or `Car` objects that you want to associate with a `Person`. Then you can optionally pass in the `home` or `car` objects when creating each `Person`. Each `home` or `car` object will have its functions available within the `Person` object too.

Comment: Thank you! One question: this `(house ? house.getAddress() : null)` is an `if else` statement. Right? Sounds like this: `if there is house get house, else null`

Comment: That's exactly right, it's just a shorter way of doing that, called a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It avoids an error if the `Person` object does not have a `House`/`Car` associated with them. 

Answer (score 1):

As I see you want to have a reference to a person's home and car in the Person object. So the only thing you need to do to make it work is to pass a House and a Car object to the Person:

```js
let Person = function (
  name,
  surname,
  yearOfBirth,
  monthOfBirth,
  dayOfBirth,
  bornCity,
  employment,
  home,
  car
) {
  this.name = name
  this.surname = surname
  this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth
  this.monthOfBirth = monthOfBirth
  this.dayOfBirth = dayOfBirth
  this.bornCity = bornCity
  this.employment = employment
  this.home = home
  this.car = car

  return {
    getFullPerson: function () {
      return {
        personalInformation: {
          name: name,
          surname: surname,
          dateOfBirth: {
            year: yearOfBirth,
            month: monthOfBirth,
            day: dayOfBirth,
          },
          bornCity: bornCity,
        },
        employment: employment,
        home: home.getAddress(),
        car: car.getCar(),
      }
    },
  }
}
```